# Stock Price Returns

Tags: python

I have a list of stock returns and need to find the year over year return.

I have created an empty list for returns and tried iterating over the list to append for the year over year returns.

```py
lst = [10.82, 18.89, 52.62, 44.29, 47.15, 39.46, 92.64, 51.28, 134.52, 180.0, 173.1, 250.87, 398.79, 310.35, 675.89, 749.87]
```

returns = []

```py
for i in range(len(lst)): 
    returns.append((lst[i+1]//lst[i])-1)
```

Returns

```
IndexError                                
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-526d26c5b374> in <module>
      2 
      3 for i in range(len(lst)):
----> 4     returns.append((lst[i+1]//lst[i])-1)
      5 
      6 print(returns)

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Is `AMZN_stock_prices` supposed to be `lst`? And think about what `i+1` is when `i` is the last index in the list.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
for i in range(len(AMZN_stock_prices)):
```

will cause `i` to vary between `0` and `len(AMZN_stock_prices)-1`. When it's at its highest value, `i+1` is outside the bounds of the list. Use

```
for i in range(len(AMZN_stock_prices)-1):
```

so that `i+1` never goes outside the bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Colin,

Assuming you are somewhat new to python. For that reason, I might operate inside of a construct that has some nice architecture around it.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
price_series = pd.Series(lst)
return_series = np.log(price_series/price_series.shift(1))  # assuming daily returns
rolling_one_year = return_series.rolling(252).sum()
```

Start there. Strongly suggest you stay inside of pandas to start your work in financial series data for many reasons. Lots of help here on stack overflow for these libraries.

Best of luck!